# Commander One -> Restart as Root

Tags: command-line, permission, root

[This article](https://www.eltima.com/wiki/user-guides/commander/restart-as-root.html) says it is possible to run Commander One as `root`. I remember I was doing something like this, but now I don't have *Restart as Root* menu item available.

How to make it work again?

I'm using

- free version of *Commander one* version 1.7.3,  from App store.
- High Sierra 10.13.3

Comment: There are at least three questions in your post, please focus on one. Also, what kind of research have you already done?

Comment: Done,  now it is only one question.

Comment: What answer did you get from https://www.eltima.com/company/contacts/ about this issue?

Comment: Nothing, they promised to reply you as soon as possible. No timeframe was specified.

Comment: If they answer me faster then the community, I'll paste their answer here as an answer.  This site will have extra piece of valuable information. Why is it bad?

Comment: https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y?rq=1

Comment: Reopened. Please clarify whether you are using the version from the website or the one from the App Store.

Comment: Thank you, patrix,  for  being a friend to me in terms of editing my post. Thank you for this helpful link about support and for making this question look better. Thank you very much. I added the version and the source of Commander one.

Comment: *but now I don't have Restart as Root menu item available* Are you saying you had it before, but now don't?  If so, what changed?  Did you upgrade the App?  macOS?

Comment: I had something similar some time ago with another computer. But it was definitely CommanderOne from AppStore for MacOS.

Comment: If you need to restart as root, enable root user and login as root. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012  This seems like product feature that overlaps an functional process in the operating system and maybe saves you one step after enabling root user. There are very few reasons you should need to login as root.  Most things can be accomplished using elevated privileges from a normal user/admin account.

Comment: I have enabled root user and restarted the CommaderOne, but the menu item still not there. I don't want to login as root, I want Commander one running as Root. It is like `sudo mc`, but with CommanderOne.

Comment: You don‘t need the root user enabled, it is just CommanderOne language for „run as admin“. I tried with the version downloaded directly from the vendor, there the option is availabe. Maybe it‘s not possible in the App Store version?

Comment: Thank you, Patrix, you saved me, I downloaded the app from the web and allowed it to control my computer. Now I have the menu item available. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are this people minusing my question. I understand the idea about - "we are not tech support team". But, in this case it is a free application and users cannot rely on support team. Free products don't come with support. Right?

Comment: No - it ios free but supplied without source by a company who make money by selling an improved version - so I would expect support. If evaluating the quality of support given would affect the likelihood of paying money - No support implies they will not get my money

Comment: Good point, Mark. Nevertheless, I don't understand why people minus me. I found a cool feature, find a lacking documentation, find a solution and put it here. It is free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to run Commander One as root, but not with commander one from `app store`.
If you download a free version from [official developer web site](https://mac.eltima.com/file-manager.html), you will have this menu item available.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to run `Commander One` without any elevated privileges? It keeps asking for password.